# Remove clipping path from selected element

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to script of Adobe Illustrator and I am facing an issue to remove all clipping path from the selection. I know one property `path.clipping = false`. But the issue that I am facing is to remove from all internal items.

Please help.

Comment: The property that you are using `path.clipping = false` is right. By all internal items you means, groups inside groups and all other pageItems inside the group items?

Comment: Yes, the groupItems may contain other groupItems, pathItems or even compound Paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This required traversing the selected item from top to bottom. Try the following method. This method traverse inside all groupItems and set `clipping = false`, if it is found to be true while traversing. I hope this helps.

```
function removeClipping(item) {
    for (var k = 0; k < item.pageItems.length; k++) {
        if (item.pageItems[k].typename == 'GroupItem') {
            removeClipping(item.pageItems[k])
        } else {
            for (var i = item.pageItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var _item = item.pageItems[i];
                if (_item.typename == "PathItem" && _item.clipping) {
                    _item.clipping = false;
                } else if (_item.typename == "GroupItem") {
                    removeClipping(_item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

removeClipping(app.selection[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, If I need to remove the clipping path instead of setting to false, then I just need to use `_item.remove()` ?

Comment: Correct, just replace `_item.clippping = false` to `_item.remove()`